# Internally rewrite a subdomain to main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I am trying to internally rewrite URLs of a subdomain:
e.g. `sub1.domain.com/something/` silently goes to to main domain `domain.com/sub1/something/`.

I have been able to get this to work properly as a redirect. However, I do **not** want them to redirect.
I still want it to show `sub1.domain.com/something/` as the URL and simply display the content from `domain.com/sub1/something/`.

Need some help achieving this. Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/sub1/$1 [L]
```

Note: both domains are pointing to the same server (and i can make them share the same document root folder, if needed)

Comment: Do you have the same document root folder for both `sub1` and main domain ?

Comment: I set up the subdomain path as a subfolder of the root domain, but I can change that if I need to.

Comment: Would it be a problem for you to share the same document root between subdomain and main domain ? In order to give subdomain access to `locations` folder. Otherwise, there's another solution using mod_proxy

Comment: I was trying to avoid having the site be accessible at both the subdomain and the main domain since that creates duplicate content for SEO...unless we can work around that with .htaccess as well?

Comment: Which I guess we will somewhat by default since sub1.domain.com/(.*) will forward to /locations/$1 so perhaps that isn't an issue at all.

Comment: I can make it whatever it needs to be - but currently it is a subfolder within the main domain root folder, named sub1